# R Plotly extendTraces: Change to incremental and clear data

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am trying out the R Streaming example for extendTraces on Plotly. I am trying to add a functionality to the chart such that it would clear all the data as the browser starts stalling after some time (eg., an actionButton, etc). Is there a way to stop the trace and clear the trace/data on a second click of the actionButton ? Alternatively, is it possible to make the chart incremental, such that the entire data isn't getting stored locally.

https://plot.ly/r/streaming/#streaming-in-r

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

rand <- function() {
  runif(1, min=1, max=9)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  includeCSS("styles.css"),

  headerPanel(h1("Streaming in Plotly: Multiple Traces", align = "center")),
  br(),
  div(actionButton("button", "Extend Traces"), align = "center"),
  br(),
  div(plotlyOutput("plot"), id='graph')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  p <- plot_ly(
      type = 'scatter',
      mode = 'lines'
    ) %>%
    add_trace(
      y = c(rand(),rand(),rand()),
      line = list(
        color = '#25FEFD',
        width = 3
      )
    ) %>%
    add_trace(
      y = c(rand(),rand(),rand()),
      line = list(
        color = '#636EFA',
        width = 3
      )
    ) %>%
    layout(
      yaxis = list(range = c(0,10))
    )

  output$plot <- renderPlotly(p)

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    while(TRUE){
      Sys.sleep(1)
      plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke("extendTraces", list(y=list(list(rand()), list(rand()))), list(1,2))
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks in advance,

- Raj.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi maybe you could do something like this?

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyjs)
rand <- function() {
  runif(1, min=1, max=9)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  # includeCSS("styles.css"),

  headerPanel(h1("Streaming in Plotly: Multiple Traces", align = "center")),
  br(),
  div(actionButton("button", "Extend Traces"),actionButton("buttonReset", "Reset Traces"), align = "center"),
  br(),
  div(plotlyOutput("plot"), id='graph'),
  useShinyjs()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues()

  values$p <- plot_ly(
      type = 'scatter',
      mode = 'lines'
    ) %>%
      add_trace(
        y = c(rand(),rand(),rand()),
        line = list(
          color = '#25FEFD',
          width = 3
        )
      ) %>%
      add_trace(
        y = c(rand(),rand(),rand()),
        line = list(
          color = '#636EFA',
          width = 3
        )
      ) %>%
      layout(
        yaxis = list(range = c(0,10))
      )


  output$plot <- renderPlotly({values$p})

  observe({
    invalidateLater(1000, session)
    req(input$button > 0)
    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
          plotlyProxyInvoke("extendTraces", list(y=list(list(rand()), list(rand()))), list(1,2))
    })
  observeEvent(input$buttonReset,{
      values$p  <- plot_ly(
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines'
      ) %>%
        add_trace(
          y = c(rand(),rand(),rand()),
          line = list(
            color = '#25FEFD',
            width = 3
          )
        ) %>%
        add_trace(
          y = c(rand(),rand(),rand()),
          line = list(
            color = '#636EFA',
            width = 3
          )
        ) %>%
        layout(
          yaxis = list(range = c(0,10))
        )
    runjs("Shiny.onInputChange('button',0)")
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Quick question - is there a way to reset the trace while the extendTrace is running in a while loop: `while(TRUE){
    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("extendTraces", list(y=list(list(rand()), list(rand()))), list(1,2))
    } ` . Alternatively, if I can stop the trace, remove the trace completely, or make the trace incremental, it would be ideal. Basically, if the stream rate is high, the browser starts stalling due to the excessive data.

Comment: @xbsd Hi I have changed the code using invaldateLater to have a continous incementation (don't know if that word exists). And some shinyjs tricks to stop it

Comment: Very nice, thanks a lot ! Knowing R and no JS has been a challenge ! :)